# Use(logic) of : operator C#

Tags: c#, syntax, operators

Can anyone explain what the ":" stands for in code. I understood the code but dont know the logic/condition behind this ":" operator.

```
public Constructor() : this("No names", string.Empty)
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you have a class with multiple constructors, so 
the

`class Constructor()`

has a **default**(no args) constructor and a constructor wit 2 strings as argument.

If some one calls the default constructor, then the class will internally call the constructor with 2 strings overloading it.

that is the explanation of that code

Comment: Thanks but i knew the explanation but that ":" was confusing me.